Python: No module named 'flask_bootstrap'
I'm trying to use a raspberryPi to pilot a relay board. Searching on internet I found this repo (https://github.com/gshau/pi-relay-controller-modmypi) that looks perfect to start.
I followed all the istructions provided and on run the server (start the server step) I have this error:
Starting Relay Controller server process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/pi-relay-controller-modmypi/server.py", line 10, in <module>
    from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_bootstrap'

I'm new with python but the meaning of the error message is pretty clear. I search and I found this stackOverflow question (Why does flask_bootstrap fail to import?) that looks my situation.
I checked the directory of virtual environment (I understood that is called 'venv', right?) ant it's /usr like described by the user author of question and answer.
My question is: why I have the variable setted wrong and how fix it?

did you try thispip install flask_bootstrap --upgrade?

Requirement already up-to-date. And on run the server the resilt is the same. I installed flash_bootstrap few minutes before, so my expectation is have all up to date
